# Getting all textareas inside a form, parse the contained text on a button click?

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea

I have a form with N textareas (each with a different name and id) and a button, which posts the form data. I want to check the content of all the N textareas for a certain pattern and only post to the form site after all patterns have been manually replaced. So, on button click I want to check all textareas for that pattern and show a window (like alert) in case there are still patterns present.

How would I do that? Is it possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to use javascript:

```
var textareaList = document.all.tags("textarea");
for(var i = 0; i < textareaList.length; i++){
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, too ... I tried, but it already fails getting the list. I placed your JS inside a function somewhere on the page where the form is and called that function when the form button is clicked. Is that correct?

Comment: maybe: document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

Comment: Do you use the textareaList in the same function?

Comment: Maybe one more thing, how do I use regex in JS? I tried: `var h = content.match(/pattern/mgi);`, but if does not find matches. The regex is correct, I checked it with some online testing tool. Ideas?

Comment: use: var reg= new RegExp(/pattern/mgi);content.match(reg);

Comment: Hm, can I assign the result of match to another var? like `var res = content.match(reg);`? My pattern is _/.*[[]#.+#[]].*/mgi_ and it should match all oocurences of [#something#] in a long string from a textarea. Do you see any problems?

Comment: Why not? Have you find a problem?

Comment: No. this function returns True or False. so?

Comment: Its not matching with my pattern ... I just dont know why. The res var is null after match was called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7426/discussion-between-hadas-and-eob)

Comment: Don’t you mean `var`, rather than `int`?

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery and a regular expression you could easily do it.

```
// Get all text areas.
$('textarea').each(function(){

   // get the value
   var value = $(this).val();

   // check the value with the regular expression here.
   // send alert if failed etc...

});
```

Comment: I can use jQuery, yes, where would I place that? In a JS function that is called when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes that is exactly where you would place it.  Or you could use it in conjunction with jquery.validate.js plugin which can also validate.  Heck it may even have a better way than what I gave you to do what you want, but you'd have to read the docs.  I don't use it past it's basic use case.

Comment: I placed it inside a js function and it was also called on button click, but something is still wrong. Can I use the code as you posted it? Do I have to replace something?

Comment: The code I have should mostly work, but you still need to add the part that checks the value for whatever your criteria is, since I don't know what that was, I just added comments to explain where to put it.  What I gave was an example, not a complete product.

Comment: It already crashed in this line: $('textarea').each(function(){